# Remove item from Local Storage

Tags: javascript, local-storage, splice, array-splice

I'm trying to remove an item from local storage. It works except it occasionally removes more than one item.

I have tried array.splice removing local storage then resetting it with the new values and haven't found a way to fix it, I'm sure it's something simple.

```
    let itemsArray = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("itemsArray")) || [];

    //Initialize Function
    window.addEventListener("load", () => showItems(itemsArray));

    //Add event listener for the form submit
    myForm.addEventListener("submit", onSubmit);

    //Add event listener for the click event on the delete button
    itemList.addEventListener("click", removeItem);

    function showItems(itemsArray) {
        itemList.innerHTML = itemsArray.join("");
    }

    //Place the input into to list of items
    function onSubmit(e) {
      //Prevent the form submission
      e.preventDefault();

        //Create li element for the DOM
        li = document.createElement("li");

        //Place input value into li
        li.appendChild(document.createTextNode(`${item.value}`));

        //Create the delete button and place it to the right of input value
        const btnDelete = document.createElement("button");
        btnDelete.classList.add("btnDelete");
        btnDelete.appendChild(document.createTextNode("X"));
        li.appendChild(btnDelete);
        itemList.appendChild(li);
        itemsArray.push(li.outerHTML);
        localStorage.setItem("itemsArray", JSON.stringify(itemsArray));

        //Reset input value to empty
        item.value = "";
    }

    //Delete item
    function removeItem(e) {
      if (e.target.classList.contains("btnDelete")) {
        if (confirm("Are You Sure You Want To Delete This Item?")) {
          removeLocalStorage();
          let li = e.target.parentElement;
          itemList.removeChild(li);
        }
      }
    }

    function removeLocalStorage(){
      let store = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("itemsArray")) || [];
      for(let i = 0; i < store.length; i++){
        store.splice(i, 1);
        localStorage.setItem('itemsArray', JSON.stringify(store));
      }
    }
```

All I want is to remove the item that corresponds to the item being deleted from the UI. When I delete, say index 1, it removes every other index.

This is essentially the Brad Traversy project on DOM manipulation. I am trying to work more with local storage for other projects.

Comment: You're not telling `removeLocalStorage` which item to remove. It's just removing every other element.

Comment: How are the items in the UI related to the elements in the array?

Comment: Please add the showItems function. Also, please see: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to pass the index of the item you want deleted to the `removeLocalStorage` function. See code below:

```
//Delete item
function removeItem(e) {
  if (e.target.classList.contains("btnDelete")) {
    if (confirm("Are You Sure You Want To Delete This Item?")) {
      let li = e.target.parentElement;
      let index = Array.prototype.indexOf.call(itemList.children, li);
      removeLocalStorage(index);
      itemList.removeChild(li);
    }
  }
}

function removeLocalStorage(index){
  let store = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("itemsArray")) || [];
  store.splice(index, 1);
  localStorage.setItem('itemsArray', JSON.stringify(store));
}
```

Comment: Yep that did the trick. I figured it was something simple I was missing. Thank You So Much!

Comment: Glad I was able to help. If the issue is completely resolved, could you mark the answer as accepted? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try the line?:

```
 window.localStorage.removeItem('itemsArray');
```

This line will delete only the item with specific key in the localstorage.

Comment: I think he just wants to remove one item from the array that's stored there, not remove the entire array.

Comment: I did try that, it worked essentially but when I refreshed the page the items where back in local storage. May have been a problem with getting local storage on the page load.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that with the loop you are removing the entire array. You have to pass an identifier to removeFromLocalStorage(). There you have to know what element you want to remove. The loop only make sense to me if you want to discover the index of an particular element with some property. For example:

```
    ...
          if (
        confirm("Are You Sure You Want To Delete This Item?")
        ) { 
        removeLocalStorage(e.target.id); 
        let li = e.target.parentElement; itemList.removeChild(li); 
}



removeFromLocalStorage(identifier){
        ...
        let id 
        store.forEach((el,index)=> {
            id = el.identifier === identifier && index
        }).
        store.splice(id,1)
        localStorage.setItem('itemArray', JSON.stringify(store))
    ....
    }
```